# How to Export and Import AD Users, Groups and Group Membership?

Tags: active-directory, csvde

Hallo,
I want to copy my Active Directory Users, Groups and Group Memberships from one DC to another using csvde, where the machines are identical except for the only the name of the Domain and Machine.
Note that each server is a DC and itself is the only member of the domain.
The command I am using for export is:

```
csvde -f C:\exportAD.csv -m -n -o "primaryGroupID,lockoutTime" -j C:\Logs\
```

I then edit the csv file, deleting a few lines which will not import, and changing the Domain and Machine name, then import it on the second machine using:

```
csvde -i -f C:\exportAD.csv -k -j C:\Logs\
```

However, this does not the group memberships present in the original.

Any ideas?

-Frink

Comment: might be better on serverfault where the gnomes from IT hang out.

Comment: Cheers Preet, I've added it there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered in https://serverfault.com/questions/181211/how-to-export-and-import-ad-users-groups-and-group-membership/229181#229181

Answer (score 0):

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=<DC Path>"
$Results = foreach( $Group in $Groups ){    
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | foreach {    
        [pscustomobject]@{    
            GroupName = $Group.Name    
            Name = $_.Name    
            }    
        }    
    }    
$Results
```

Comment: Can you provide more details (i.e. how to run this script, in which environment) and explain how it works.